# Beamer, alltt environment and \only

Tags: beamer

I have got the following problem using an `alltt` environment in a beamer document. I placed an `alltt` environment inside a block environment. Then all line breaks are correct in the output document. But if I enclose the block with an `\only` command, the line breaks in the `alltt` environment are removed. How can I remove this problem? A minimal example is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
This text should be on all 3 overlays.
\only<1,2>{
\begin{block}<1,2>{}
\footnotesize
\begin{alltt}
[user@{\color{red}nodeXX} ~]\$ {\color{blue}module load comp/gcc/4.5.1}
[user@{\color{red}nodeXX} ~]\$ {\color{blue}module load mpi/openmpi/1.6.0}
[user@{\color{red}nodeXX} ~]\$ {\color{blue}mpirun ./prgm}
\end{alltt}
\end{block}
\begin{block}<2>{}
Next Step...
\end{block}
}
\begin{block}<3>{}
This block is shown next directly below the text.  
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If the \only is commented out, the alltt environment creates the lines breaks but block 3 is  at the bottom  of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\defverbatim`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\defverbatim[colored]\mycode{
\footnotesize
\begin{alltt}
[user@{\color{red}nodeXX} ~]\$ {\color{blue}module load comp/gcc/4.5.1} 
[user@{\color{red}nodeXX} ~]\$ {\color{blue}module load mpi/openmpi/1.6.0} 
[user@{\color{red}nodeXX} ~]\$ {\color{blue}mpirun ./prgm}
\end{alltt}
}

This text should be on all 3 overlays.
\only<1,2>{
\begin{block}<1,2>{}
\mycode
\end{block}
}
\begin{block}<2>{}
Next Step...
\end{block}
\begin{block}<3>{}
This block is shown next directly below the text.  
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]